# Elliptic curve-point at infinity

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

In my lecture notes we have the following:

$$P \oplus  Q \oplus  R =O \Leftrightarrow P, Q, R \text{ are collinear }$$

So $$P \oplus  Q \oplus  O =O \Leftrightarrow Q=-P$$

that means that $Q=-P$ and $P$ is at a perpendicular  to the $x-$axis line.

($O$ is the point at infinity)

Can you explain to me why the following stands?

So $$P \oplus  Q \oplus  O =O \Leftrightarrow Q=-P$$

that means that $Q=-P$ and $P$ is at a perpendicular  to the $x-$axis line.

**Edit**:

If $P=(x, y)$, then $-P=(x, y^{\star})$.

$y$ and $y^{\star}$ are roots of $$y^2+(a_1x+a_3)y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$$

So $$y+y^{\star}=-a_1 x - a_3 \Rightarrow y^{\star}=-y-a_1x-a_3$$

We have done the first step.

If $P=(x, y)$ then $-P=(x, -y-a_1x-a_3)$.

Points of order $2$.

If $P=(x, y)$ is of order $2$ $$\Leftrightarrow P \oplus P=O \Leftrightarrow P=-P \Leftrightarrow (x, y)=(x, -y-a_1x-a_3) \\ \Leftrightarrow y=-y-a_1x-a_3 \Leftrightarrow 2y=a_1x-a_3 \overset{ ch K \neq 2}{ \Leftrightarrow } y=\frac{-a_1x-a_3}{2} $$

Can you explain to me why $P=(x, y)$ and $-P=(x, -y-a_1x-a_3)$ are points of order $2$ ???

Comment: Do you understand how the group law works? How you join two points on the curve, look at the third point of intersection (if there is one) and *reflect* this last one throught the $\;y-axis\;$ and stuff? If you do then what you ask is trivial, and if you don't (which is what happens, apparently) then perhaps you should better dive slightly deeper into the group law. Try the following for some cool diagrams: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Answer (score 1):

One has  that $O$ is the neutral element with respect to the group law $\oplus$.

So $P \oplus Q \oplus O = P \oplus Q$ and $P \oplus Q = O$ is essentially the definition of $Q = - P$ as $-P$ denotes the inverse element of $P$, and $Q$ apparently is the inverse element of $Q$ as  $P \oplus Q = 0$.

For the second part of the question recall from the geometric construction used to add points  that the point at  infinity $O$ can be thought of as "infinitely far away" on the $y$-axis. Thus the line passing through $O$ and $P$ will be parallel to the $y$-axis, and its (third) intersection with the curve, so $Q$, is thus what you described.

---

For the edit: A point $P$, and more generally an element of a commutative group, is called of order $2$ if $2P = P + P = 0$, equivalently $P = -P$ (and $P$ is non-zero). The point is to establish when a point is of order $2$. We have for a general point $P= (x,y)$ that the $x,y$ need to fulfill the equation, else they would not be points on the curve. Now, above we saw that the inverse of the point $-P$ is the "other" point with very same  $x$. So we find the second coordinate of  this point. Then $P$ is of order $2$ *if* in fact $P = - P$ so that the two second coordinates coincide. To this end we compare the two expressions for the second coordinate of $P$ and $-P$. If they are equal $P= -P$ and $P$ is a point of order $2$, if not then not as $P \neq -P$.

Comment: I understand quid! I added also an other question at the post above. Can you help again?

Comment: Great. I tried to answer the edit too. But it is often better to ask a new question and not to have too many questions in one.